# Process of uploading to a server

Tags: java, android, mysql, proftpd

There doesn't seem to be a comprehensive explanation of the exact process being undertaken for uploading files from an android device to a server. So far I have pieced together some information on the methods for preparing the data however the "plugging in" if you will is somewhat more confounding.

What is it that is absolutely necessary for the transaction to take place? What information is required on the app side and what is the server looking for? How does the server get the data without first being preprogrammed to receive it?

I feel that simply setting up a ftp server is not enough so I'm wondering what else is involved. Any help for a novice would be gladly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to upload files (any format) from your_android app to your_server ??

Comment: Specifically the address of the server and the subsequent functions of the server necessary to facilitate the transaction.